# Autopostback prevents button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, events

I have an asp.net page and on it there are a number of controls, including:

1. A textbox with `autopostback = true` and the server side `textchanged` event implemented
2. A button with the server side click event implemented

The textbox performs the postback as soon as the user leaves the control (ie, focus is lost).  The problem is that if the user happens to change the value and then press the button without leaving the textbox, then on button click the textbox will perform the postback but the button click will be lost.

How can i force both the textbox and the button events to fire consecutively in such cases?

Thanks

Comment: how can user click the button without leaving textbox? button click always force leave focus on textbox and set focus to button... you can try to add some delay before request...

Comment: What i meant is that he doesn't leave textbox before pressing the button.  ie as soon as he clicks button, the focus is lost and the textbox autopostbacks.  but the button click event doesn't fire then

Comment: Give the same event name for both control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="display:none" Text="Button" />
```

JS:

```
function EnterEvent(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            __doPostBack('<%=Button1.UniqueId%>', "");
        }
    }
```

CS:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delay postback from textbox and cancel it in case of button click. To do this add code below to `Page_PreRender` method:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.OnClientClick = string.Format("if(window.{0}Timeout){{ clearTimeout(window.{0}Timeout); }}", 
        TextBox1.ClientID);

    TextBox1.Attributes["onChange"] = string.Format("javascript:window.{0}Timeout = setTimeout(\"{1}\", 500); return;", 
        TextBox1.ClientID, 
        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(TextBox1, ""));
}
```